# How to show row number in HTML template and use it as unique id?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I want to use the row ID/row number in order to easily identify which row of the database to delete/update.
I don't have any unique key other than row ID/row number.

How can I show the column in my HTML page and how do I use it in the SELECT command in SQL?

(SQLite, Python, Flask, Template_rendering, HTML)

Flask:

```py
@app.route("/")
def index():
con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
   
c = con.cursor()
c.execute("select * from ordersList")
   
rows = c.fetchall()
return render_template('index.html', rows=rows)
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>Item Name</td>
        <td>Order For</td>
        <td>Order Date</td>
        <td>Shipping Date</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </thead>
            
    {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            <form>
                <td>{{row["rowid"]}}</td>
                <td>{{row["ItemName"]}}</td>
                <td>{{row["OrderFor"]}}</td>
                <td>{{row["OrderDate"]}}</td>
                <td>{{row["ShippingDate"]}}</td>
                <td>{{row["Status"]}}</td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like you're already including `rowid` in your data, just not in your header? Can you explain what you mean by 'using it in the SELECT command'? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want 2 things:
1. Show the rowid as numbers in the HTML page
2. Use the rowid in the FLASK file as a primary key. I want to edit/delete specific row from my DB, but I don't know how to use "rowid" correctly.

Right now the "rowid" in the HTML code doesn't work, I added it to demonstrate what I want to present

Comment: We have to assume your table `ordersList` actually contains these columns, including `rowid` - is that correct? Have you set up the SQLite database to use the rowid as a primary key? You don't need to, to use it to erase rows, but you'd want it to be unique at least and setting it as a key would speed things up. Also, can you indicate why you added `rowid` as an html table row, but not as a `td` in the `thead`?